IIS AspNetCore Module V2 failed to load coreclr, yet the application pool is running and returning 503
I am having a new issue on my Windows Server 2022 IIS running my application. The issue is intermittent and only occur when doing starting the application pool. The Application Pool runs 3 workers and I can see the following error in the Event Logs:

Source:IIS AspNetCore Module V2
Event ID 1034
Could not load configuration. Exception message: Unexpected exception: Configuration load exception has occurred
Process Id: 4436.
File Version: 16.0.24211.33. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit: f0f9de5692adf1c0576de062f93c6ab7b176433f
Source:IIS AspNetCore Module V2
Event ID 1034
Application '/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/myapp/services' with physical root 'C:\myapp\services' failed to load coreclr. Exception message:
Unexpected exception: HRESULT 0x8007023e returned at D:\a_work\1\s\src\Servers\IIS\AspNetCoreModuleV2\InProcessRequestHandler\inprocessapplication.cpp:474

From my analysis, this impacts only one worker out of 3 (Process Id: 4436). From memory utilization, I can see process id 4436 is unhealthy. In addition, the application return error 503 intermittently, which I suspect is when the unhealthy worker process the request.
I can't find the root cause or any logs that would help me.
I can't reproduce the issue on-demand, but it happens frequently.
IISRESET solves the issue.
Any idea?
Thank you

The error itself points to this line of code, https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v6.0.33/src/Servers/IIS/AspNetCoreModuleV2/InProcessRequestHandler/inprocessapplication.cpp#L474 which boils down to an exception from https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Servers/IIS/AspNetCoreModuleV2/InProcessRequestHandler/InProcessOptions.cpp#L9. Further debugging is needed to learn more about what happens at runtime. If you are not familiar with native debugging, you might report to GitHub https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues?q=is%3Aissue+iis+%220x8007023e%22

I suggest you could install the newest hosting bundle to test, if this is still not working, I suggest change the inprocess to the outofprocess to test.

@BrandoZhang ANCM version 16.0.24211.33 is already the latest, as part of .NET 6.0.33.

Thanks for mention it, how about install the previous version  ASP.NET Core Runtime 6.0.32 to test if this is related with the runtime, then create a github issue.
